# How to make script work to set IP address of ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, command-line, bash, scripts

On Ubuntu 22.04 I have the following script

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="enx00e04c681730"
echo "Interface: $INTERFACE set to IP $1"

ifconfig $INTERFACE down
ifconfig $INTERFACE $1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

which is supposed to change the IP address of the specified adapter. After I set the execution flag

```
 chmod ugo+x set_address.sh
```

I call it like

```
sudo ./set_address.sh 169.254.1.100
```

but the IP address of the given interface has not been updated.

When I run the commands myself manually

```
 sudo ifconfig enx00e04c681730 down
 sudo ifconfig enx00e04c681730 169.254.1.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

it works just fine. But not with the script.

But if I run now the actual script again, like

```
sudo ./set_address.sh 192.168.200.100
```

THEN it works as it should.

How to "fix" this issue so the script works even without running the `ifconfig` commands myself in the first place?

Comment: You might want to try 'ip' instead: https://ubuntu.com/blog/if-youre-still-using-ifconfig-youre-living-in-the-past

Comment: Maybe you should consider using netplan instead, which is the default configuration method on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: I tried netplan already but it did not work

Comment: @davidbaumann How to use "ip"? I tried `sudo ip addr add 169.254.1.100/24 dev enx00e04c680202` to change the IP address of the adaptor but it did not work. The address has not been changed

Comment: I also get the error `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` ...

Comment: Does it work if you run it from a bash with root permissions? (start that with `sudo -i`)

Answer (score 0):

you can try the script like bellow, it works fine in my VM.

```
#!/bin/bash

INTERFACE="enx00e04c681730"
echo "Interface: $INTERFACE set to IP $1"

ip address flush dev $INTERFACE
ip address add $1/24 dev $INTERFACE
ip link set $INTERFACE up
```

Answer (score 0):

The script and the method of running the scripts look good. If the manual command process is working but not the script then there is some issue related to *the timing of bringing the interface down and back up*. You can try adding a **sleep** command between bringing the interface down and setting the new IP address. *This might give the system enough time to complete the down operation before moving on to the up operation.*

```
#!/bin/bash
INTERFACE="enx00e04c681730"
echo "Interface: $INTERFACE set to IP $1"

sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE down
sleep 5  # Adding a 5 sec short delay to allow the interface to go down
sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE $1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

You can adjust the sleep duration based on your system or specific requirements. *Additionally, ensure that the assigned IP address is within the same **subnet** as the one you're connecting to, and verify that the **DHCP** server isn't allocating the IP to another device.*

Additionally, using the full path to commands in scripts is a good practice. Modify the **ifconfig** commands to use the full path, like `/sbin/ifconfig` or `/usr/sbin/ifconfig`, to avoid any potential issues with the script's *inability to locate the command*. The path of the command can be found with `which ifconfig`.